# Laravel route to custom function in controller does not work

Tags: php, laravel

**laravel 5.3**

I'm trying to make a button or link execute the activate function in the AdminController, though whenever i click the button it gives me the 404 page saying it can't find AdminController@activate.

When i use dd() from the function it doesn't do anything.

If you need any other information please say so, i'm in no way a laravel expert :-)

**Admin middleware**

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class admin
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
       if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->level == 2)
       {
           return $next($request);
       }
       return abort(401, 'Unauthorized');
   }
}
```

**Web Routes**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.admin']], function() {
    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
    Route::get('/admin/{id}/delete', 'AdminController@delete');
    Route::get('/admin/activate', 'AdminController@activate');
});
```

**AdminController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AdminController extends Controller
{       

    public function activate(){
       $users = User::where('active', 0)->get();
       $users->active = 1;
       $users->timestamps = false;
       $users->update();
       $users->timestamps = true;
       return redirect('admin');
   }
}
```

**HTML/blade**

```
<a href="{{ url('/admin/activate') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true">Activate all</span></a> <br>
    @foreach ($data['inactiveusers'] as $user)
        {{$user->firstname}} {{$user->surname}}
        <a href="{{ url('/admin/' . $user->id .'/edit') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        <a href="{{ url('/admin/' . $user->id .'/delete') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        <br>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: In HTML, specify the method as GET.

Comment: He's using some links so he shouldn't have to specify any method

Comment: Debug : Move the /admin/activate out of the middleware and try access directly

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen great call, apparently there's something wrong with the middleware cause i can access it outside of it.
For some reason i couldn't do auth::check() and check the user level in the same if statement

Comment: Are you sure the request is going from authenticated source i.e., Is the user logged in while accessing the url ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Yes, it is fixed now. Thanks :-D

Comment: @JelmerBeerling Posted an answer which would help further readers +1 for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

The laravel [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#introduction) won't give access to the url that is protected to the unauthenticated users.

**How can i fix this ?**

Make sure that the user is authenticated for the url that you're requesting

**Tip :**

Move the /admin/activate out of the middleware and try access directly. It should work

**Worst Hack :**

You can disable this from your `middlewareGroups` inside your `Kernal.php` but this is not recommended.